# FF4J usage from play framework

Tags: playframework, ff4j

I am trying to use FF4J from project developed with Play Framework. When I am trying to use my own strategy (extending AbstractFlipStrategy) it fails with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. 
The exception is in line

```
           flipStrategy = (FlippingStrategy) Class.forName(clazzName).newInstance();
```

in org.ff4j.conf.XmlParser. 
I assume that I can overcome it by extracting my strategy to external project and including it via build.sbt. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I am getting the same `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` failure attempting to extend AbstractFlipStrategy in my project. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: i don't remember, i suppose i did. i don't work on that project anymore and have no access to sources.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for responding though. I appreciated that. I've temporarily gone with another solution and will report back here if I find a true solution.

Comment: @NarutoSempai, yes, i extracted it to separate project. Let me know if you still need it.

Comment: Yes it would be very helpful if you are able to share it!